# Difference Between AppFabric and Redis?

Tags: azure, caching, redis, appfabric-cache, session-state-provider

I am currently working on a ASP.NET MVC application.Currently it is using AppFabric for storing session and cache data.But Microsoft has stopped support for AppFabric.Microsoft is using Redis for cache management and is supported by Azure.
What is the difference between AppFabric and Redis in terms of speed,size of data and performance?How Redis is different than AppFabric?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the following post, "Mainstream Support will be provided until 4/11/2017 and Extended Support until 4/12/2022."

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2015/06/19/appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server-support-lifecycle-extension-4-11-2017.aspx

This means you are not without support yet. However, Microsoft does recommend that all application using AppFabric should migrate to Redis Cache. See this entry in MSDN for Cache Recommendations.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn766201.aspx

How is Redis better/different than AppFabric...

First, AppFabric was actually contained a number of technologies including, Service Bus, Access Control Service, and Caching

see also: [Azure AppFabric vs. Server AppFabric - today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820312/azure-appfabric-vs-server-appfabric-today)

Second, from a caching perspective, AppFabric was more closely aligned with .Net. Redis as an Open Source NoSQL database store is usable by a broad set of technologies including Python, Ruby, Java, PHP, Node, C, C#.

Third, since its keys can store data structures like strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets, bitmaps, and hyperloglogs, it is generally more flexible than other caching solutions.

There is a migration guide here, if you want to see what might be involved with moving to Redis Cache.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690524.aspx

Comment: To use redis do we require Azure license?